# Change Container size based on number of tiles

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout, storyboard

I have one container view, which has 8 tiles of equal height and equal width.User will add and remove these tiles.If user remove tiles then container height height decrease and if user add tiles than container height increase. Maximum 8 tiles can be added and removed. Do any know how is it possible using auto layout?

[image]

Screenshot have 8 tiles with constraint. Constraint for first tile view is **top** and **leading** to **Container view**, **Height** and **Width** **equal to Second tile view**, **Trail** to **Second tile view**, **Bottom** to **Third tile view** and **Height** set to **129** fixed.I have used "NSLayoutConstraint" and set height to "0" but it doesn't remove from container.

Comment: Can you tell me why you don't use `UICollectionView` here?

Comment: Managing auto layout for a flexible number of views is very cumbersome. `UIStackView` is a good and simple alternative.